# Evaluate Text to Decimal Issue (EVALUATE Navision)

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, evaluate, navision

I am having an issue when trying to evaluate a text into decimal.
First thing, I am doing an extraction of values between the ; symbol from a field in NAV (The field is of type Text)

`My field value is: 9 469;2 178;0;-1 000;0;0;0;37 994,96;1 000;0;0;0;493,4;0;0;0;`

When extracting, it becomes to:

```
Example: 
9 469
2 178
-1 000
etc..
```

After extracting, I need to convert the text to a decimal which is of:

```
CodeConvert := '9 469'

EVALUATE(Primo,DELCHR(CodeConvert,'=',' '));
```

But when doing the Evaluate, I do get an error message of:

> ### Microsoft Dynamics NAV
>
> The value "9 469" can't be evaluated into type Decimal.
>
> ### --------------------------- OK

Comment: Most probably character between numbers is not a space. Tab maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue for this. Actually there was a special character which NAV was inserting in the space in the decimals. If ever you use delchr and visually it is a space ' ' and it is not deleting.

Then your best friend is notepad. Extract the value on notepad and copy & paste that spacing ' ' to your delchr function. Conclusion, it was not a space being added but a special character and since visualy it appeared as a space, first impression was it is a space :)

Worked like this for me!

Answer (score 0):

I try this and work fine in NAV 2009, 2013, 2015 and 2016, this is my code:

```
CodeConvert := '9 469;2 178;0;-1 000;0;0;0;37 994,96;1 000;0;0;0;493,4;0;0;0;';
CodeConvert := COPYSTR(CodeConvert, 1, 5);
EVALUATE(Primo, DELCHR(CodeConvert, '=', ' '));
MESSAGE(FORMAT(Primo));
```

Try this code and use the debugger to see step by step:

```
CodeConvert := '9 469;2 178;0;-1 000;0;0;0;37 994,96;1 000;0;0;0;493,4;0;0;0;';
CodeConvert := COPYSTR(CodeConvert, 1, 5);
CodeConvert := DELCHR(CodeConvert, '=', ' '); //here your breakpoint
EVALUATE(Primo, CodeConvert);
MESSAGE(FORMAT(Primo));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the `EVALUATE` function breaks on "9 469" value.

But `DELCHR` should remove the space BEFORE the `EVALUATE` is called.

It only means that the space symbols in your value and in delchar are different.

Select and copypaste the symbol from "9 469" to the third argument in `DELCHAR`.